# jquery autocomplete should not search WITHIN words

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, filtering

I am using a jquery input form, autocomplete, by category, as follows :

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#categories

Imagine my whole list contains :

```
Mario
Super Mario
AntiMario
```

If I write "Mario", the 3 results match but I don't want the 3rd one to.
The rule should be something like:

```
"Search for 'Mario' ONLY at the beginning of the string or after a ' ' space"
```

which seems complicated.

Any great idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you have to make your own custom AJAX function and get result according to My SQL query..